# Roku Automation using java

Tags: java, automation, roku

We are going to automate Roku TV application , but we are wondering if there is any automation testing tools to use in order to make this possible?
testing is gonna be done using Java framework.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For now, the only automated testing is the [Roku Remote Tool](http://devtools.web.roku.com/RokuRemote/index.html). This just allows you to set up an automated series of remote inputs to test that user actions do not crash the application (I haven't found much further use for this myself). However, the steps are timed, so if the screen isn't ready for the next automated remote input, then you can induce an error, but more importantly you'll be out of step with your testing sequence. It's not a very good solution in my opinion, but it's all they've given us. The unit testing framework from Roku has matured a lot, and is very useful if you want to implement a TDD - unit testing approach (this would let you automate testing before your builds). Aside from those, I'm not sure how you have planned to test with Java, as I'm not aware of any such integrations. Good luck with your channel!

Answer (score 2):

I could advice you [MAMUT](https://www.mamuttool.com/). This is a special tool for unit testing of Roku applications. All test scripts must be written in BrightScript, so you don't need to learn any new programming language if you already develop applications for Roku. I guess it is much nicer than to create test scripts in Java. You can check [the sample test suite](https://github.com/RomanPodymov/MAMUT) to see how it is easy to test Roku applications with MAMUT.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the [Rokuality project](https://github.com/rokuality) It's an image/ocr based tool written in the flavor of selenium. Available in java now but support for other language bindings coming soon.

Comment: Wanted to mention the Rokuality project now has bindings in C#, Python, and Java. And the latest version 1.2.4 includes support for the new Roku WebDriver API.